# How do I make a floating div dynamically expand to take up maximum space?

Tags: html, css, formatting

I have 3 floated left objects, the one on the left will change in size all the time. The right on will always be fixed in size. The center one I want to fill up the space between the two outer divs. Right now that's not working though. If I set the width of the center div to 100% it gets way too big.

Not sure how this should be handled.

edit: code sample

```
<div style="width:1000px">
  <div style="float:left;">1</div>
  <div style="float:left;">Lots of text in here that can be any size....</div>
  <div style="float:left; width:100px;">Date/Time</div>
</div>
```

The first div is dynamic in size. If the number is 10 it's going to take up more space than the number 1. The second div will be dynamic as well, I want that to take up whatever space isn't take up by the first and third div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:1000px">
  <div id="left">1</div>
  <div id="right">Date/Time</div>
  <div id="center">Lots of text in here that can be any size....</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left {
    float: left;   
    width: 20%;
}

#center {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;   
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6G6Xs/).

Comment: It doesn't seem like the margin-left actually works in that case, at least the fiddle you linked me to is doesn't have a margin

Comment: If it was working there would be a space between the two colors right? In the fiddle you sent I see each element next to each other as if it was in a table.

Comment: That's just how floats work. Try to remove `margin-left: 20%` and add more text in `#center` then you will see what I mean.

Comment: Well I was assume that there would be a way for me to treat it like a normal div. But it seems that with this method that isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>How do I make a floating div dynamically expand to take up maximum space?</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #left {
        float:left;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    #right {
        float:right;
        border:1px solid green;
        width:100px;
    }
    #center {
        overflow-x:hidden;
        border:1px solid blue;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>How do I make a floating div dynamically expand to take up maximum space?</h1>

    <div id="left">
    Un-fixed width left, whose content may change.
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    Fixed WIdth Right column which shouldn't expand.
    </div>
    <div id="center">
    The center content<br />Which should expand as necessary
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably found this out long ago, but for the next guy, you can do this now with CSS3 flexbox. ([W3c's newest specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/), [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="expandable">Lots of text in here</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100px;">Date/Time</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}   
.expandable {
    flex: 100 100;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slushy/kk81nwxr/).

Comment: Looks like flexbox is a complicated way to achieve what tables achieve out of the box.